# Essential supremum definition

Tags: measure-theory

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_supremum_and_essential_infimum

From the definition here I'm unable to tell, whether we have to take the infimum, or whether we could take a minimum - does a minimum not always exist? I can't think of an example where

$$\mu({\{g > a}\}) > 0$$

and yet $$\operatorname{ess sup} g = a $$

Does such an example exist?

Comment: no, an example like that doesn't exist. can you clarify your question?

Comment: If the essential sup of $g$ is $a$ then all the sets $\{g>a+1/n\}$ have measure zero and their union is $\{g>a\}$. This implies that $\{g>a\}$ also has measure zero.

Comment: Thanks. mm-aops: I was asking, because if such an example does not exist, it seems to me that $min\{{a: \mu({\{g>a}\})=0}\} =  inf\{{a: \mu({\{g>a}\})=0}\} $ is true, right? It's simply a bit unclear to me, why we would use the infimum as opposed to minimum, if we know a minimum always exists. I guess it doesn't really matter, I just feel it's more intuitive to do so if we can.